# Passing a bidimensional array to function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

the program should return the differenze between the sums of the elements in the two diagonals of a matrix, however it only seems to work with certain values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 2

int SommaDIag(int *mat);

int main(){
    int mat[N][N] = {{3, 2},
                     {6, 2}};

    return SommaDIag(mat);
}

int SommaDIag(int *mat){
    int rig, col, somma = 0;

    for(rig = 0, col = 0; rig < N && col < N; rig ++, col++)
        somma += *(mat + col + N*rig);

    for(rig = N-1, col = 0; rig >= 0 && col < N; rig --, col++)
        somma -= *(mat + col + N*rig);

    return somma;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int SommaDIag(int *mat)
```

will be

```
int SommaDIag(int (*mat)[N])
```

Array decays into pointer to first element when passed to the function. Here `mat` is an array of arrays. So the pointer to the first element would be `int(*)[N]`.

Solution is to change the function signature like as I said `int SommaDIag(int (*mat)[N])`.

```
int SommaDIag(int (*mat)[N]){ // SommaDIag(int mat[][N])
    int rig, col, somma = 0;

    ...
}
```

Also you can get the difference easily like this -

```
for(rig = 0, col = 0; rig < N && col < N; rig ++, col++)
   somma += mat[rig][col];
```

---

When you pass a 1D array of `int` to a function it will decay into pointer to the first element - in this case the first element being an `int` variable - apointer to it would be `int*`.

```
int a[10];

f(a);

void f(int *a){ // f(int a[])
  ...
}
```

Comment: so what sould i do?

Comment: @AntonioPavan get familiar with diff on how to pass 1D array vs 2D array.

Comment: I'm trying to but found no sources for such topic, any suggestion?

Comment: @AntonioPavan.: You can check the answer I explained a bit

Comment: @coderredoc Also `int mat[][N]` as the formal argument could do and you may mention that.